# Rails 4 x simple_calendar gem: create new record on click in calendar cell

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, calendar

I have a Rails 4 app with a `Post` model and a `Calendar` model: a `post` `belongs_to` a `calendar` and a `calendar` `has_many` `posts`.

The `Post` model has a custom `:date` attribute.

Posts are displayed in two alternative views:

- As a list in the standard `Calendars#Show` view
- As a calendar in the custom `Calendars#Calendar_view` view

What I am trying to achieve, is to allow users to simply click in a cell of the calendar in the `Calendars#Calendar_view` view to create a new post, that is to say to go to the `Posts#New` view, where the `:date` field of the new post will be pre-filled with the date from the cell.

I am using the [simple_calendar gem](https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar) in a the `calendar_view` view to display the posts, with the following code:

```
<%= month_calendar events: @posts do |date,posts| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: "new-event", data: {date: date} do %>
    <%= date.strftime('%e') %>
    <% posts.each do |post| %>
      <div class="single_event">
        <%= link_to post.subject, post_path(post) %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I am using this code in my `posts.coffee` file to detect the `on click` event and grab the date from the cell:

```
$(".new-event").on "click", (e) ->
  date = $(this).data("date")
  window.location = "/posts/new?post[date]=#{date}"
```

Then, in my `Posts#New` action, I am using `@post = @calendar.posts.new(post_params)` to pre-load the date from the cell in the form.

The problem is: when I click in a cell in the `calendar_view` view, nothing happens.

I checked the console in Chrome, and no error appears.

Any idea what is going wrong here, or at least where I should start to debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this example: https://github.com/excid3/clickable-simple_calendar

You can use this JS to trigger the redirect. I was wrong with the location redirect, this one is what you want:

```
jQuery ->
  $(".calendar-day").on "click", ->
    date = $(this).data("date")
    location.href = "/meetings/new?meeting[start_time]=#{date}"
```

This all hooks up to the HTML for the calendar:

```
<%= month_calendar do |day| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: "calendar-day", data: {date: day} do %>
    <%= day %>
    <%# Whatever else you want in here %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And there's a little change the the Meetings new action that prepopulates it with the param using strong_params (and also doesn't throw an error if it's missing).

That should do the trick!